# base de datos sql

Tags: python, sql

Estoy probando un ejercicio para desactivar un perfil de una base de datos, pero cuando entro en la ruta para borrar el perfil me da un error diciendo que la columna "inactive" no existe os paso el trozo de codigo:

```
@app.route('/delete', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def delete():
    session_token = request.cookies.get("session_token")
    user = db.query(User).filter_by(session_token=session_token, inactive=False).first()

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("delete.html")

    elif request.mehod == "POST":
        user.inactive = True
        db.add(user)
        db.commit()
        return redirect(url_for("/"))
```

Y el codigo del archivo models.py:

```
import os
from sqla_wrapper import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL", "sqlite:///localhost.sqlite"))

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    secret_number = db.Column(db.String, unique=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    session_token = db.Column(db.String)
    inactive = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

Y este es el error que da :

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such
>   column: users.inactive [SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name
>   AS users_name, users.email AS users_email, users.secret_number AS
>   users_secret_number, users.password AS users_password,
>   users.session_token AS users_session_token, users.inactive AS
>   users_inactive  FROM users

Answer (score 0):

Abre la base de datos y mirale si esta creado la columna, aunque la solucion me parece que debes llamar users_inactive  en vez de user.inactive = True ejemplo

```
user.users_inactive  = True
```

Comment: no habia reseteado la base de datos.... hehe, ya esta. Gracias!